# Adopting Visual Studio 2010 for Development

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I am using Visual Studio 2008 for development. But would like to switch to Visual Studio 2010  as I can better compiler and libraries and compatible with Windows 7 etc.

But in the view Windows 8, we've seen a new express edition of Visual Studio 11. Any roadmap available for the Visual Studio 11 release?

Comment: what are you asking? about 2008, 2010 or 2011?

Comment: I updated the question. Sorry for wrongly phrasing it.

Answer (score 0):

2011 will probably be released around the same time Windws 8 will, so this might well be a year away. A specific release date is speculation in the current state. If you want to profit by a better IDE and the possibilities that .NET 4 provides, you can do this now without having to fear that you could "upgrade" in month or so again.

Comment: I only have GUI part which make use of .NET service. Others are native C++ code.

Comment: One of the main benefits then is - I think - a better IDE. I'm not very active in C++ code so I don't know if there are breaking changes.